# Rewriting all file when save some changes

Tags: git, saving, diff

I work on Rails project in my **Emacs25**.

When I change one specific file and save changes I got all file changed (from git diff).
But when I try to old and new versions of this file in **Meld** - I get difference with only my few strings changes.

In this .rb file has linux line separator, 2 spaces tabulation just like in whole project. 
There is a place to be only in this file (maybe other files has it but the most of don't).

Most important thing: I changed this file before many times with no problems.

Config information:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say "linux line separator" (by which I assume you mean it uses Unix-style LF line separators) yet your snapshot shows `(DOS)` in the modeline, hence CRLF line separators.  My crystal ball tells me that's the source of your problem.